# No 'Add friend' facility on Facebook

Tags: facebook-friend-request

Found old friend on Facebook. Sent message. Message accepted. Facebook says 'you and so & so are not connected on Facebook'. How do we send a friend request?

Answer (score 2):

I think your friend has a privacy setting for **Who can send friend requests?**. If your friend has set it as **Friends of friends** and you both do not have any mutual friends, you will not see **Add friend** button or if your friend has set it **No One**, in that case **Add Friend** button will not visible on his/her profile.

Another case is may be your friend already has friends to the limit (5000). In this case he/she will not be able to add more people as a friend.

People can select the audience they want to receive friend requests from in their settings. You might consider sending your friend a message and asking them to friend you.

To know about friend requests privacy see this [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/217125868312360/) article.